# Move inline CSS on find-user page to proper class

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, design

On the `/admin/find-users` page, there's some inline CSS to color even rows in a table. It would be nice if those could be moved to a proper class to allow for adjustment through user styles.

```css
td,th { padding:3px 17px } tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #eeeeee; }
```

Comment: Why can't you adjust them as they are?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Then they'll affect all tables on the mod pages. There were no `id` or `class` properties to further limit the selector only to that table.